# Probabilities in stochastic model

Tags: probability, biology

I am trying to understand the stochastic model of growth cell.

In this model the cell cycle time $c$ is assumed to be constant. However.
each cell independently of every other cell gives birth to a random number $0$,$1$ or $2$ offspring with probabilities $p_0$,$p_1$,$p_2$ respectively.

[image]

From the fig. it is evident that the number of offspring in the first generation is not determined with certainty, but only that $Z_1 = 0,1,2$ with probabilities $p_0$,$p_1$ ,$p_2$ respectively.

Now, here the situation is more complicated for generation $2$.The book said that the probabilities of $Z_2$ (where the number of descendants $Z_k$ of a single cell or ancestor in the $k$th generation is not a constant but a random variable)

> > Here, I really don't understand how they get these probabilities:
> >     $$P(Z_2=0) = p_0+p_1p_0+p_2p_0^2,$$
> >     $$P(Z_2=1) = p_1^2+2p_2p_1p_0,$$
> >     $$P(Z_2=2) = p_1p_2+2p_2^2p_0+p_2p_1^2,$$
> >     $$P(Z_2=3) = 2p_1p_2^2,$$
> >     $$P(Z_2=4) = p_2^3,$$

I am biologist, and this is a little bit difficult, Could someone can help me to know how the book get these probabilities?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an illustrative example of the first case using conditional probability

$$P(Z_2=0) \\ = P(Z_1=0,Z_2=0) \qquad + \qquad P(Z_1=1,Z_2=0) \qquad+ \qquad P(Z_1=2,Z_2=0) \\ = P(Z_1\!=\!0)P(Z_2\!=\!0 \!\mid\! Z_1\!=\!0) \!+\! P(Z_1\!=\!1)P(Z_2\!=\!0 \!\mid\! Z_1\!=\!1) \!+\!P(Z_1\!=\!2)P(Z_2\!=\!0 \!\mid\! Z_1\!=\!2) \\= p_0 \qquad\times\qquad 1 \qquad+\qquad p_1 \qquad\times\qquad p_0 \qquad+\qquad p_2 \qquad\times\qquad p_0^2 \\= p_0+p_1p_0+p_2p_0^2$$

Comment: sorry, but why $P(Z_2=0∣Z_1=1) = p_0$

Comment: @Rachel Given that $Z_1=1$ (i.e. there is exactly one individual in Generation $1$), the conditional probability that $Z_2=0$ (i.e. there are no individuals in Generation $2$) is the probability the one individual in Generation $1$ has no offspring, which is $p_0$

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So for the $P(Z_2=1) = P(Z_1=0,Z_2=1)+P(Z_1=1,Z_2=1) + P(Z_1=2,Z_2=1)=$ $ P(Z_1=0)P(Z_2=1|Z_1=0) +P(Z_1=1)P(Z_2=1|Z_1=1)+P(Z_1=2)P(Z_2=1|Z_1=2)$ ?

Comment: But, is this correct? $P(Z_1=0)P(Z_2=1|Z_1=0) = p_0 \times 1$, $P(Z_1=1)P(Z_2=1|Z_1=1) = p_1 \times p_1$ and $P(Z_1=2)P(Z_2=1|Z_1=2) = p_2 \times p_2$ ?

Comment: @Rachel - no it is not correct.  $P(Z_1=0)P(Z_2=1 \mid Z_1=0) = p_0 \times 0$ since if there are no individuals in generation $1$ then they cannot have any offspring.  Meanwhile $P(Z_1=1)P(Z_2=1\mid Z_1=1) = p_1 \times p_1$ as you found but $P(Z_1=2)P(Z_2=1 \mid Z_1=2) = p_2 \times (p_0\times p_1 + p_1 \times p_0)$ as one of the two individuals in Generation $1$ would need to have one offspring and the other no offspring